# couchdb - new views checkpointing against huge update_seq

Tags: view, couchdb, revisions

I am running couchdb 0.11 on mac os x in a development environment. I have about 50,000 documents which I have migrated from a mysql db. In the course of migration, I have deleted and reimported this data about 15 times and now the update_seq on the database is around 900,000. Now, when I add new views (or modify current ones), the build takes forever as it checkpoints against all of the previous (now-deleted) revisions of each document. I get nearly 1M lines of "checkpointing view update at seq 132299 for"... (where the seq goes to nearly 900k).

I am not replicating this db at this time and have no need for old revision stubs etc. I just want to be able to build views against existing documents and discard the old revision data (and metadata)!

I have tried db compaction, view cleanup, and view compaction several times. Nothing seems to make a difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Mike. After compaction, the old document revisions are definitely gone. I suggest setting a baseline to compare against. Replicate to a fresh database (on a different but similar machine if possible) and see how long that takes. That can help determine the difference between the existing DB and the new one.

Also, remember that creating or modifying a view will rebuild from scratch; that's the nature of CouchDB.